# How do I generate xsd from dataset.xsd in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd, xsd.exe

Using Visual Studio 2010 in a generic C# project, I've created a DataSet (DataSet1.xsd) and dragged my table onto it.  I can see the table in the designer view.

I want to see the raw .xsd file based on this DataSet.

I don't want to write the .xsd by hand, I want to generate the .xsd based on a database table.

I've looked into using xsd.exe, but it only converts XSD to DataSet, not the other way around.

Perhaps there's a better approach than the methodology I'm trying here, just seems fast and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to right click on the DataSet1.xsd in Visual Studio. Select "Open With". Choose "XML (Text) Editor". Now you should be able to see the raw .xsd file.

If you go to the local path of the DataSet1.xsd you can also open it with for example notepad or another text editor.

Hope this was what you looked for.

Comment: Correct, simple and timely!